# Impose a condition on std::max_element

Tags: c++, algorithm, vector, iterator

Is there any way to make `std::max_element` return the `end` iterator if no element is grater than a certain value?

Imagine I have this vector:

```
std::vector<int> vector{3, 6, 2, 5};
auto it = std::max_element(vector.begin(), vector.end());
```

How would you make `it` point to `vector.end()` if no element is greater than 7?

Comment: [boost::filter_iterator](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_59_0/libs/iterator/doc/filter_iterator.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see an algorithm to do this directly, but it's pretty trivial to tack it on after the fact:

```
auto temp = std::max_element(v.begin(), v.end());
auto it = (temp ==v.end() || *temp > 7) ? temp : v.end();
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I thought it could be done, but I didn't know if there was a way to do it in one function.

Comment: @PabloRamónGuevara - The way to do it in one function is to write that template yourself. It's not that hard to accept a pair of iterators + other things, and replace `v.end()` by `it_last`.

Answer (score 1):

With [range-v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3), you may do:

```
std::vector<int> v{3, 6, 2, 5};
auto r = v | ranges::view::filter([](auto e){ return e > 7; });
auto it = ranges::max_element(r);
if (it == r.end()) {
    std::cout << "End\n";
} else {
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;   
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/97e456b848370c16)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to use external libraries

Comment: Is `r.end()` the same as `v.end()`?

Comment: @KerrekSB: type are different. And I got a compile error with `it == v.end()` unfortunately.

Comment: One of the problems with filters in general is that boundary iterators are potentially ambiguous with regards to the source (= unfiltered) range...